# Upgrading Reinforced.Typings to 1.4.0 from 1.3.7 crashes build

Tags: c#, xml, typescript, msbuild, code-translation

I've just upgraded my C# 4.5.1 .NET lib called "ViewModels" to the latest 1.4.0 version of the `Reinforced.Typings` lib/tool via NuGet (the tool enables converting my C# to .ts files).

After the upgrade I declined overwritting the .xml config file and diffed it manually with the newly proposed readme.txt file which now has the .xml defaults to see if any major changes were introduced. From what i saw the  xml tag lost its attributes which signal the build process the tools version etc, more precisely these attrs were excluded in 1.4.0:

```
ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
```

So, now the build crashes informing me to bring those back with the error message as follows:

> Severity  Description File    Code    Project Line    Suppression State
>   Error The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML
>   namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format,
>   please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
>   to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old
>   1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\REDACTED\ViewModels\Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml      ViewModels  2

Bringing the previous xml attrs to the  tag resolves the issue and opens two new issues that seem related to RtCli of the Reinforced.Typings lib which I can not surpass, the errors are:

> Severity  Description File    Code    Project Line    Suppression State
>   Error The "RtCli" task could not be initialized with its input
>   parameters.           ViewModels

and...

> Severity  Description File    Code    Project Line    Suppression State
>   Error The "BuildDirectory" parameter is not supported by the "RtCli"
>   task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable
>   public instance property.         ViewModels

I am happy to see an upgrade to the tool but for the time being I am reverting to 1.3.7 as I am not facing these issues over there.

It would be great if someone (hey there author) could help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to clean up your local NuGet cache. Usually it is located in `C:\Users\%username%\.nuget\packages\`. Remove reinforced.typings directory from there. After that, reinstall Reinforced.Typings.

It seems that for some reason you have old version of RT's integration MSBuild task ([source](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/blob/master/Reinforced.Typings.Integrate/RtCli.cs)). Sometimes it happens that MSBuild process locks tasks assembly and does not allow to remove its .dll. Try to also to kill MSBuild processes from task manager.

Regarding .settings.xsml header - I will mention it in the readme.txt, but actually it works ok in VS2017 (msbuild 15).

Comment: OK, will try, would be cool if you mention this issue also somewhere (if this will fix it, OFC will let you know here). Thanks.

Comment: that seem to be it... still had to add the mentioned attributes, also saw that some new 'Microsoft.' dependencies were added in my project references.